# общий баланс с примером массива(объектов)

Tags: javascript

задание Дополни функцию getTotalBalanceByGender(users, gender) так, чтобы она возвращала общий баланс пользователей (свойство balance), пол которых (свойство gender) совпадает со значением параметра gender.

помогите понять в чем ошибка консоль не выдает ответа вовсе

```
[
  {
    name: "Moore Hensley",
    email: "moorehensley@indexia.com",
    eyeColor: "blue",
    friends: ["Sharron Pace"],
    isActive: false,
    balance: 2811,
    gender: "male"
  },
  {
    name: "Sharlene Bush",
    email: "sharlenebush@tubesys.com",
    eyeColor: "blue",
    friends: ["Briana Decker", "Sharron Pace"],
    isActive: true,
    balance: 3821,
    gender: "female"
  },
  {
    name: "Ross Vazquez",
    email: "rossvazquez@xinware.com",
    eyeColor: "green",
    friends: ["Marilyn Mcintosh", "Padilla Garrison", "Naomi Buckner"],
    isActive: false,
    balance: 3793,
    gender: "male"
  },
  {
    name: "Elma Head",
    email: "elmahead@omatom.com",
    eyeColor: "green",
    friends: ["Goldie Gentry", "Aisha Tran"],
    isActive: true,
    balance: 2278,
    gender: "female"
  },
  {
    name: "Carey Barr",
    email: "careybarr@nurali.com",
    eyeColor: "blue",
    friends: ["Jordan Sampson", "Eddie Strong", "Adrian Cross"],
    isActive: true,
    balance: 3951,
    gender: "male"
  },
  {
    name: "Blackburn Dotson",
    email: "blackburndotson@furnigeer.com",
    eyeColor: "brown",
    friends: ["Jacklyn Lucas", "Linda Chapman", "Adrian Cross", "Solomon Fokes"],
    isActive: false,
    balance: 1498,
    gender: "male"
  },
  {
    name: "Sheree Anthony",
    email: "shereeanthony@kog.com",
    eyeColor: "brown",
    friends: ["Goldie Gentry", "Briana Decker"],
    isActive: true,
    balance: 2764,
    gender: "female"
  }
]
```

,
вот что сделал я

```
const getTotalBalanceByGender = (users, gender) => {
   return [...users].map(user => user.gender).filter(user => user.gender === gender).reduce((totalBalance, usr)=> 
totalBalance += usr.balance, 0)
};
```

Comment: вызвать функцию может стоит?

Comment: что-то мне кажется `...users` не нужно,и  `filter` можно исключить, обработав в reduce как `totalBalance + usr.gender == gender ? usr.balance : 0` либо умножение вместо тернарного

Answer (score 2):

Тут 1 ошибка.

- `users.map(user => user.gender)` превратит массив `users` в `['male', 'female', 'male', 'female', 'male', 'male', 'female']` и вы уже не сможете с ним работать как с `users`

Не ошибки, но лишнее усложнение:

- Не нужна деструктуризация `[...users]`
- Зачем добавлять дополнительный проход по массиву c `filter`, если все можно сделать в одном проходе в `reduce`?

Должно получиться что-то вроде этого:

```js
const users = [{
    name: "Moore Hensley",
    email: "moorehensley@indexia.com",
    eyeColor: "blue",
    friends: ["Sharron Pace"],
    isActive: false,
    balance: 2811,
    gender: "male"
  },
  {
    name: "Sharlene Bush",
    email: "sharlenebush@tubesys.com",
    eyeColor: "blue",
    friends: ["Briana Decker", "Sharron Pace"],
    isActive: true,
    balance: 3821,
    gender: "female"
  },
  {
    name: "Ross Vazquez",
    email: "rossvazquez@xinware.com",
    eyeColor: "green",
    friends: ["Marilyn Mcintosh", "Padilla Garrison", "Naomi Buckner"],
    isActive: false,
    balance: 3793,
    gender: "male"
  },
  {
    name: "Elma Head",
    email: "elmahead@omatom.com",
    eyeColor: "green",
    friends: ["Goldie Gentry", "Aisha Tran"],
    isActive: true,
    balance: 2278,
    gender: "female"
  },
  {
    name: "Carey Barr",
    email: "careybarr@nurali.com",
    eyeColor: "blue",
    friends: ["Jordan Sampson", "Eddie Strong", "Adrian Cross"],
    isActive: true,
    balance: 3951,
    gender: "male"
  },
  {
    name: "Blackburn Dotson",
    email: "blackburndotson@furnigeer.com",
    eyeColor: "brown",
    friends: ["Jacklyn Lucas", "Linda Chapman", "Adrian Cross", "Solomon Fokes"],
    isActive: false,
    balance: 1498,
    gender: "male"
  },
  {
    name: "Sheree Anthony",
    email: "shereeanthony@kog.com",
    eyeColor: "brown",
    friends: ["Goldie Gentry", "Briana Decker"],
    isActive: true,
    balance: 2764,
    gender: "female"
  }
]

const getTotalBalanceByGender = (users, gender) => {
  return users.reduce((totalBalance, usr) => {
    if (usr.gender != gender) return totalBalance;
    return totalBalance + usr.balance;
  }, 0);
};

console.log(getTotalBalanceByGender(users, 'male'));
console.log(getTotalBalanceByGender(users, 'female'));
```

Если нужен однострочник:

```
 const getTotalBalanceByGender = (users, gender) => users.reduce((total, user) => user.gender === gender ? total + user.balance: total, 0);
```

Comment: _деструктуризация [...users]_ - это тоже не ошибка, а усложнение

Comment: @Grundy поправил

Comment: Можно возращать и без `+=`, а сразу с `+`

Comment: Что еще не так?)

Comment: можно убрать `if`: `users.reduce((totalBalance, usr) => totalBalance + usr.balance * (usr.gender == gender), 0)`

Comment: @Grundy Любишь же ты эти преобразования :)

Comment: @Grundy да не, не буду уж на такую конструкцию менять. Человек в методе `map` запутался, а тут еще приведение типов, которое, хоть и прикольно выглядит, может быть не очевидно.

Comment: Ну вообще, чисто чтобы сократить код, можно без `return` и использовать тернарный оператор, а для безопасности использовать строгое сравнение :)

Comment: Всем спасибо, но есть вариант еще более легкий, разобрался и через фильтр сделал


const getTotalBalanceByGender = (users, gender) => {


return users.filter(user => user.gender === gender).reduce((totalBalance, user)=> {
return totalBalance + user.balance}, 0);
};

Comment: @максим он не легкий. Вы делаете двойную работу вызывая `filter` и `reduce` в чейнинге. Если вам так нужен однострочник, который будет относительно быстро отрабатывать, то принимая все описаные выше замечания должно получиться ``const getTotalBalanceByGender = (users, gender) => users.reduce((total, user) => user.gender === gender ? total + user.balance: total, 0);``